# How to avoid or remove metadata from Iot GetThingShadow API. Metadata is a part of response and which increasing size of payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

`enter code here`{
"state": {
"desired": {
"welcome": "aws-iot"
},
"reported": {
"welcome": "aws-iot"
}
},
"metadata": {
"desired": {
"welcome": {
"timestamp": 1702544546
}
},
"reported": {
"welcome": {
"timestamp": 1702544546
}
}
},
"version": 1,
"timestamp": 1702544734
}